# Android: add 3 events at once

Tags: android, events, calendar

i've got this code

```
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Integer.parseInt(data_scelta_splittata[2]),Integer.parseInt(data_scelta_splittata[1]),Integer.parseInt(data_scelta_splittata[0]),Integer.parseInt(ora_scelta_splittata[0]),Integer.parseInt(ora_scelta_splittata[1]));
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
                intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
                intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
                intent.putExtra("allDay", "allDayFlag");
                intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=DAILY");
                intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
                intent.putExtra("title", "Avviso Bioscalin "+prodotto);
                startActivity(intent);
```

the problem is that i need to add 3 events at the same time, this code add an event and prompt to the user the calendar adding pre-compiled, but i can't do this 3 times, it's boring for the user. any idea?

Comment: no, because i don't know if it resolve the problem for the user

Comment: Not sure but I somehow doubt that you can add an event without user interaction (easily). Have you tried using the calendar api to an event? Maybe that is the way to go...

Comment: yes but i can't find the calendar_id needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working in 4.0+, there is [CalendarContract](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.html) for that. Before ICS, though, your choices are a bit more limited. Even the event you're launching now won't work on Android devices where the manufacturer has replaced the Calendar app.

There isn't any way to manipulate the vnd.android.cursor.item intent to be silent or to execute multiple requests. Additionally, while you can interact with the Calendar app through various intents, this interaction is not documented and so not recommended.

What you might consider instead is using the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) to interact with the user's calendar via REST. As long as the calendar you want to interact with is the one associated with the user's Google account, this approach will give you code that would work on any Android API level, as well as on devices where the stock Calendar app has been replaced. The drawback is that it won't give you the ability to add events to a user's Outlook calendar.

Comment: i've resolved using this: http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm